# Updating MySQL database when user closes browser

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a web application for a research company and one of the requirements is that a user can only log in on one device at a time.

So I developed a pretty basic system where when you log in some PHP updates a user's row in the database from 0 to 1 and when you click the logout button it updates that row again from 1 to 0.

The only problem is if the user does not use the logout button and simply closes the browser, it will end the session and log them out but their row in the databse will not be updated.

Is there a way to update the database on browser close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unload event where you will send an ajax request to server which will update the flag in mysql. You can try following jquery syntax.

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        url: 'path/to/file.php'
    });
});
```

Comment: @AzzyDude Now turn off javascript (or have a javascript error on some page). Close the browser. Try to log in. It's not a bad solution, but keep in mind that it's not 100% reliable, like I said in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but we have a message if JavaScript is turned off. They can't break our system with it off, their service will just be crap. So it's in their interest to keep it on.

Comment: How do you get this value on the php side? do you set a variable to $_GET .. then what?

Answer (score 5):

There is no reliable way. You can call a javascript function on page close, which in turn fires a request to your server, telling it that the session is done, but again: javascript may be turned off, and it may not even executed at all. Your best bet is to work with a time-out: store the time of the last action. If longer than 10 minutes ago, "expire" the session.

Comment: Yeah, we're implementing a cronjob for that. But it's just in case they accidentally close the browser, then they can't get back in for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for browser close event. I faced some issue with "onunload" and "beforeonunload" events. It will be triggered for browser close, tab close, any link click, URL change. So i customized my code like this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
          var validNavigation = false;

          // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
          $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 116){
              validNavigation = true;
            }
          });

          // Attach the event click for all links in the page
          $("a").bind("click", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          });

          // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
          $("form").bind("submit", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          });

          // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
          $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          }); 

          window.onbeforeunload = function() {                
              if (!validNavigation) {                            
                 var status = 'abandoned';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: your action URL,
                        data: "status=" + status,
                        success: function(res) {
                        },
                    });
              }
          };
        }); 
    </script>
```